# case_when ignores some arguments when using group by

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a longitudinal dataset with individuals of different socioeconomic statuses (SES) divided into 4 classes, high, mid, low mid, and low. For some of the analyses, I only want to show the sample size for low mid group if *both* the mid and low class groups have at least 5 individuals for that month's observations. Otherwise, I want it to show as NA.

I thought this code would work, but it doesn't. It should give NA the low mid group's 'adjusted_total' column in Jan, but keep it as its current value (40) for Feb. It fails to do the former but accomplishes the latter:

Here's my sample dataset and attempt at getting what I wanted using dplyr's case_when():

```
library(dplyr)

#Sample dataset
test_data <- tibble(month = c(rep(c("Jan"), 4), rep(c("Feb"), 4)),
                    ses = c(rep(c("High", "Mid", "Mid Low", "Low"), 2)),
                    total = c(10, 20, 4, 30, 9, 11, 40, 60),
                    total_selected = c(9, 10, 8, 3, 8, 6, 8, 6))

#Failed attempt
wrong <- test_data %>%
group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(adjusted_total = case_when(
    ses == "Mid Low" & total[ses == "Mid"] <5 | total[ses == "Low"] <5 ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ total
  ))
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

I realized that I had a typo in my code. First, I meant an or statement, not an AND. Second, the threshold was too low for my data. When I adjust to an OR statement and the cut off to 15

```
correct <- tibble(month = c(rep(c("Jan"), 4), rep(c("Feb"), 4)),
                    ses = c(rep(c("High", "Mid", "Mid Low", "Low"), 2)),
                    total = c(10, 20, 4, 30, 9, 11, 40, 60),
                    total_selected = c(9, 10, 8, 3, 8, 6, 8, 6)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(adjusted_total = case_when(
    ses == "Mid Low" & total[ses == "Mid"] < 15 | total[ses == "Low"] < 15 ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ total
  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when/ifelse/if_else` all requires the arguments to be of same length.  Here, one of the logical expression  is of different length.  A correct approach would be to wrap with `any` of the subset of 'total'

```
test_data %>%
group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(adjusted_total = case_when(
    ses == "Mid Low" & any(total[ses  %in% c("Mid", "Low")] < 15) ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ total
  )) %>% 
ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  month ses     total total_selected adjusted_total
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Jan   High       10              9             10
2 Jan   Mid        20             10             20
3 Jan   Mid Low     4              8              4
4 Jan   Low        30              3             30
5 Feb   High        9              8              9
6 Feb   Mid        11              6             11
7 Feb   Mid Low    40              8             NA
8 Feb   Low        60              6             60
```

---

Or with `replace`

```
test_data %>%
   group_by(month) %>% 
   mutate(adjusted_total = replace(total,
    ses == "Mid Low" & any(total[ses %in% c("Mid", "Low")] < 15), 
    NA)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it still doesn't produce the appropriate NA

Comment: @J.Sabree your example doesn't show a case for that i.e. `test_data %>% filter(ses %in% c("Mid", "Low"), total < 5)` or `test_data %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(new = any(ses %in% c("Mid", "Low") & total < 5)) %>% ungroup` it shows all FALSE

Comment: @J.Sabree Based on your description, are you looking for `test` where ses value "Mid Low" to be less than 5?

Comment: I found the typo in my code and addressed it in the prompt. It's now fixed and can be closed. Thank you!

Comment: @J.Sabree still that soluiton is incorrect because of the length dissimilarity

Comment: but it runs successfully for this dataset

Comment: @J.Sabree just by chance only because of recycling.  Try it on a different data where there are duplicates of "Mid", "Low" or one absent and this could have different length issue

Comment: @J.Sabree what I meant is that your expression `total[ses == "Mid"]` returns a single value per group.  Creating a logical expression on that will recycle the values.  It may not be the case for each group generally